# Is this use of rebind_alloc an error?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-asio

In an official example of boost.asio, I find the following code:

```
template <class Func, class Alloc>
void post(Func f, const Alloc& a) const
{
  auto p(std::allocate_shared<item<Func>>(
    typename std::allocator_traits<
    Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<char>(a),
    priority_, std::move(f)));
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(context_.mutex_);
  context_.queue_.push(p);
  context_.condition_.notify_one();
}
```

Should `rebind_alloc<char>` be modified to `rebind_alloc<item<Func>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. The specification for `allocate_shared` says:

> The `allocate_shared` templates use a copy of `a` (rebound for an unspecified `value_type`) to allocate memory.

The function never allocates the pointee directly anyway; it typically allocates a shared_ptr control block with embedded pointee instead. Therefore any allocate you pass will have to be rebound anyway.

The advantage of rebinding to `char` is that it is shorter, and doesn't have to be adapted for the type used. (`int` may be even shorter, but `char` is sometimes understood to mean "raw memory".) The advantage of rebinding to the pointee type is that it is less confusing for other programmers.